# Python crashes either when using recursion one too many times or accessing a large list

Tags: python

```
size = len(numbers)
tree = [None] * size * 3

def build_tree(numbers, root, node, element):
        if element != 0 and element != size:
            if tree[node] < numbers[element]:
                if tree[node + 2] is None:
                    tree[root] = numbers[element]
                    tree[node + 2] = root
                    build_tree(numbers, root + 3, 0, element + 1)

                else:
                    build_tree(numbers, root, tree[node + 2], element)

            elif tree[node] > numbers[element]:
                if tree[node + 1] is None:
                    tree[root] = numbers[element]
                    tree[node + 1] = root
                    build_tree(numbers, root + 3, 0, element + 1)

                else:
                    build_tree(numbers, root, tree[node + 1], element)

        elif element == 0:
            tree[root] = numbers[element]
            build_tree(numbers, root + 3, 0, element + 1)


build_tree(numbers, 0, 0, 0)
```

I wrote this function for an assignment I had and it works as intended, but only for up to about 300 integers. After that it crashes and I haven't been able to figure out why. Same thing happens for my C implementation of the very same code.

The function builds a binary search tree, the values are taken from the numbers array.

```
   tree[0] > value of node
   tree[1] > index of right child
   tree[2] > index of left child
```

to give an example,
`tree[tree[2]]` would give us the value of left child of `tree[0].`

Here's the result:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

Comment: Recursion isn't well suited for "large problems". If you need to recurse many times, you should change the implementation to avoid recursion. In Python, you can make the stack larger, but that's only a temporary solution.

Comment: Your code does not seem to be full. At least `tree` is not defined. Please, clarify the question.

Comment: Also, please explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: The actual result is: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison". The function doesn't return anything at all, so it's unclear what "works as intended" means - especially when `numbers` is undefined.